# How to get top n records group by wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table example:

```
+--------+-------------+
| id     | city_detail |
+--------+-------------+
| 1      | 12_hyd_test |
| 2      | 13_blr_test |
| 3      | 15_blr_test |
| 4      | 18_hyd_test |
| 5      | 17_coi_test |
| 6      | 22_coi_test |
| 7      | 62_hyd_test |
| 8      | 72_blr_test |
| 9      | 92_blr_test |
| 10     | 42_hyd_test |
| 11     | 21_coi_test |
| 12     | 82_coi_test |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

From this table, how to use like condition with group by to select like this

```
+--------+-------------+
| id     | city_detail |
+--------+-------------+
| 12     | 82_coi_test |
| 11     | 21_coi_test |
| 10     | 42_hyd_test |
| 7      | 62_hyd_test |
| 9      | 92_blr_test |
| 8      | 72_blr_test |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

In each city show only two result (`%coi%` or `%hyd%` or '`%blr%'`) order by id `DESC`

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I tried this query select id,city_detail from tble_name where ( city_detail like '%coi%' OR city_detail like '%hyd%' OR city_detail like '%blr%' ) order by id desc

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest method is to use variables:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = substr(city_detail, 4), @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := substr(city_detail, 4), 1, 1
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from example e cross join
           (select @c := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by substr(city_detail, 4)
     ) e
where rn <= 2;
```